# Control Flow Logic while parsing peculiar flat hierarchy HTML w BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, date, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to compile a dict from this [HTML](http://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/chicago/free-outdoor-summer-movies-chicago) and it has an unusual flat HTML. The format is also peculiar in that it doesn't provide the date for each movie title, for has movie titles playing that day listed under the date (some have one, some have multiple).

This is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="caption">
    <strong>July 1</strong>
    <br>
    <em>Top Gun</em>
    <br>
    "Location: Millennium Park"
    <br>
    "Amenities: Please be a volleyball tournament..."
    <br>
    <em>Captain Phillips</em>
    <br>
    "Location: Montgomery Ward Park"
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>July 2</strong>
    <br>
    <em>The Fantastic Mr. Fox </em>
```

I wrote a code that works 80% of the way - it only outputs the last movie listed under each date. So it's clearly overwriting the dictionary if there are multiple movies that are siblings of the `<strong>`(which is "date") tag.

What I want to do is find the date variables, for each date variable, hold the date value constant, find and store the loc/title/amenities values in variables, if/when we run into another date value("") or title(""), we write the dictionary that we have to the file - but if it's a title(""), we keep rolling with the same date value we affixed first.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

URL = 'http://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/chicago/free-outdoor-summer-movies-chicago'

html = urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

with open("MovieParks.tsv", "w") as f:
    categories = ['Location', 'Movie Title', 'Date', 'Amenities']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter = '\t', fieldnames = categories)
    writer.writeheader()

    root = soup.find_all("strong")
    for row in root:
        master_dict = {'Location':"", 'Movie Title':"", 'Date':"", 'Amenities':None}
        for sibling in list(row.next_siblings)[:-1]:
            Date = row.text.encode('utf-8')
            master_dict['Date'] = Date
            if sibling.name == "strong":                
                break
            if sibling.name == "em":
                MovieTitle = sibling.text.encode('utf-8')
                master_dict['Movie Title'] = MovieTitle
                if sibling.next_sibling == "em":
                    writer.writerow(master_dict)
                    break
                    sibling = sibling.next_sibling
            if 'Location:' in sibling:     
                Location = sibling.replace("Location: ","") + ", Chicago"
                master_dict['Location'] = Location.encode('utf-8')
            if 'Amenities:' in sibling:
                #not every item has Amenities listed
                Amenities = sibling.replace("Amenities: ","")
                master_dict['Amenities'] = Amenities.encode('utf-8')


        writer.writerow(master_dict)

print 'Done here'
```

My troubled current output (which is only listing the info of the last movie under each date header on the site):

```
Location    Movie Title Date    Amenities
Edgebrook Park, Chicago A League of Their Own   June 7  Family friendly activities and games. Also: crying is allowed.
Gage Park, Chicago  It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World June 9  Family friendly activities and games.
Commercial Club Playground, Chicago Despicable Me 2 June 12 Family friendly activities and games.
```

etc.

I can't help but feel like I'm not far off, just can't figure out the control flow logic required.

Comment: Hi SpicyClubSauce. Do you recall how you go on with the contribution in the answers below? It is not strictly mandatory to response to answers here, but we do encourage it. If you can accept it now, that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Now is the time to start refactoring. I refactored logic for processing all subsequent movies within one date into a separate method :

```
def processMovies(em, date):
    master_dict = {'Location':"", 'Movie Title':"", 'Date':"", 'Amenities':None}
    MovieTitle = em.text.encode('utf-8')
    master_dict['Movie Title'] = MovieTitle
    master_dict['Date'] = date

    for sibling in em.next_siblings:
        if sibling.name == "strong":
            writer.writerow(master_dict)
            return
        if sibling.name == "em":
            writer.writerow(master_dict)
            processMovies(sibling, date)
            return
        if 'Location:' in sibling:     
            Location = sibling.replace("Location: ","") + ", Chicago"
            master_dict['Location'] = Location.encode('utf-8')
        if 'Amenities:' in sibling:
            #not every item has Amenities listed
            Amenities = sibling.replace("Amenities: ","")
            master_dict['Amenities'] = Amenities.encode('utf-8')
```

And in the main method you can simply find the first movie (`<em>` tag) in each `<strong>`, and pass the movie to `processMovies()` :

```
with open("MovieParks.tsv", "w") as f:
    categories = ['Location', 'Movie Title', 'Date', 'Amenities']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter = '\t', fieldnames = categories)
    writer.writeheader()

    root = soup.find_all("strong")
    for row in root:  
        date = row.text.encode('utf-8')
        movie = row.find_next_sibling('em')
        processMovies(movie, date)
```

Above codes successfully write *all movies* to `.tsv` file for me.